# How to filter out distinct array value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to filter an array of json objects by unique value.

My structure is like this.

```js
var arr1 = [{
    "badgeNumber": "111",
    "firstName": "Frank",
    "lastName": "Tank"
  },
  {
    "badgeNumber": "111",
    "firstName": "Frank",
    "lastName": "Tank"
  },
  {
    "badgeNumber": "222",
    "firstName": "Frank",
    "lastName": "Tank"
  }
];

var arr2 = [];

for (let line of arr1) {
  arr2.push({
    id: line.badgeNumber,
    text: line.badgeNumber
  });
  arr2.push({
    id: line.firstName,
    text: line.firstName
  });
  arr2.push({
    id: line.lastName,
    text: line.lastName
  });
}

console.log(arr2);
```

desired output:

```
[
0{id: "111", text: "111"}
1{id: "Frank", text: "Frank"}
2{id: "Tank", text: "Tank"}
3{id: "Frank", text: "Frank"}
4{id: "Tank", text: "Tank"}
5{id: "222", text: "222"}
6{id: "Frank", text: "Frank"}
7{id: "Tank", text: "Tank"}
]
```

I've tried this; which is close but it filters out all the ids.  I only care about id with value badgeNumber

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    let item = arr2[i];
    if(itemsObj[item.id]) {
        itemsObj[item.id] = item;
        arr2Filteredpush(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: That desired output is **NOT** filtering them based on unique value. you'd just replicated them

Comment: Did I misspeak?  The id 111 is not repeated in my desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Set` that holds the badge numbers that have been added, and check whether the badge is in the set before pushing it.

```js
var arr1 = [{
    "badgeNumber": "111",
    "firstName": "Frank",
    "lastName": "Tank"
  },
  {
    "badgeNumber": "111",
    "firstName": "Frank",
    "lastName": "Tank"
  },
  {
    "badgeNumber": "222",
    "firstName": "Frank",
    "lastName": "Tank"
  }
];

var arr2 = [];
var badges = new Set();

for (let line of arr1) {
  if (!badges.has(line.badgeNumber)) {
    arr2.push({
      id: line.badgeNumber,
      text: line.badgeNumber
    });
    badges.add(line.badgeNumber);
  }

  arr2.push({
    id: line.firstName,
    text: line.firstName
  });
  arr2.push({
    id: line.lastName,
    text: line.lastName
  });
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Thank you!  @Barmar this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution without using additional variable:

- double [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to build a map with unique keys
- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get all object keys and values as array
- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to return only values of generated map

```js
const arr1 = [{
    badgeNumber: '111',
    firstName: 'Frank',
    lastName: 'Tank'
  },
  {
    badgeNumber: '111',
    firstName: 'Frank',
    lastName: 'Tank'
  },
  {
    badgeNumber: '222',
    firstName: 'Frank',
    lastName: 'Tank'
  }
];

const arr2 = Object.values(arr1.reduce((res, curr, ind) => ({
  ...res,
  ...Object.entries(curr).reduce((res, [key, text]) => ({
    ...res,
    [key === 'badgeNumber' ? text : `${key}_${text}_${ind}`]: {
      id: text,
      text
    }
  }), {}) 
}), {}));

console.log(arr2);
```

This solution does not keep the order of the original array. If the order is important, [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) may be used (as already mentioned by @Barmar):

```js
const arr1 = [{
    badgeNumber: '111',
    firstName: 'Frank',
    lastName: 'Tank'
  },
  {
    badgeNumber: '111',
    firstName: 'Frank',
    lastName: 'Tank'
  },
  {
    badgeNumber: '222',
    firstName: 'Frank',
    lastName: 'Tank'
  }
];

const arr2 = [...new Map(arr1.reduce((res, curr, ind) => ([
  ...res,
  ...Object.entries(curr).reduce((res, [key, text]) => ([
    ...res,
    ...[[(key === 'badgeNumber' ? text : `${key}_${text}_${ind}`), {
      id: text,
      text
    }]]
  ]), []) 
]), [])).values()];


console.log(arr2);
```